# New Firefox blocking svg images

Tags: firefox, svg

My svg images used to work fine in firefox but now with new version they're all gone.

What should I change with these to make these work again:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 6000 6000"><path d="M4685.5,873.8c820.3,646.1,602.7,2625.6-336.7,3687.9c-1024.4,1158.6-2278.4,1461.8-3194.1,679.5 C-578.6,3760.5,3082.6-388.7,4685.5,873.8z" style="fill:#edac5a"/></svg>
```

Comment: Displays fine to me. Which new version do you mean?

Comment: Hi Robert so 55 works. 56 doesnt show anything. 57 beta crashes the browser...

Comment: Both 56 and a nightly display fine for me. Try safe mode.

Comment: Thanks Roberts. You're correct. The issue was in css in the end with this:
           transform-style: preserve-3d;

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1397671